# simply put data on top of another pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

i have 2 sample datasets dfa and dfb:

```
import pandas as pd


a = {
 'unit': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
 'count': [ 1, 12, 34, 52]   
}

b = {
 'department': ['E', 'F'],
 'count': [ 6, 12]   
}
dfa = pd.DataFrame(a)
dfb = pd.DataFrame(b)
```

they looks like:

```
dfa
count unit
   1    A
  12    B
  34    C
  52    D


dfb 
count department
 6          E
12          F
```

what I want is simply have dfa stack on top of dfb not based on any column or any index. i have checked this page: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html but couldn't find the right one for my purpose.

my desired output is to create a dfc that looks like below dataset, i want to keep the headers:

```
 dfc:

count     unit
   1        A
  12        B
  34        C
  52        D
count  department
  6          E
 12          F
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
You can construct it from scratch using `np.vstack`

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.vstack([dfa.values, dfb.columns, dfb.values]),
    columns=dfa.columns
)

   count        unit
0      1           A
1     12           B
2     34           C
3     52           D
4  count  department
5      6           E
6     12           F
```

**Option 2**
You can export to csv and read it back

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv(StringIO(
        '\n'.join([d.to_csv(index=None) for d in [dfa, dfb]])
    ))

   count        unit
0      1           A
1     12           B
2     34           C
3     52           D
4  count  department
5      6           E
6     12           F
```

Comment: i like option1 the best because I can put more than 2 datasets in that one line. your option2 is good too but option1 is more straightforward to me

Answer (score 3):

```
In [37]: pd.concat([dfa, pd.DataFrame(dfb.T.reset_index().T.values, columns=dfa.columns)], 
                   ignore_index=True)
Out[37]:
   count        unit
0      1           A
1     12           B
2     34           C
3     52           D
4  count  department
5      6           E
6     12           F
```

or

```
In [39]: dfa.append(pd.DataFrame(dfb.T.reset_index().T.values, columns=dfa.columns)) \
            .reset_index(drop=True)
Out[39]:
   count        unit
0      1           A
1     12           B
2     34           C
3     52           D
4  count  department
5      6           E
6     12           F
```

**UPDATE:** merging 3 DFs:

```
pd.concat([dfa,
           pd.DataFrame(dfb.T.reset_index().T.values, columns=dfa.columns),
           pd.DataFrame(dfc.T.reset_index().T.values, columns=dfa.columns)],
          ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: if there are more than 2 datasets, how to put all of them in one line?

Answer (score 0):

```
dfa.loc[len(dfa),:] = dfb.columns
dfb.columns = dfa.columns
dfa.append(dfb)
```